# How do I stop gdal_polygonize from connecting polygons completely?

Tags: gdal

I have a grib2 file that I am polygonizing using the command :

```
gdal_polygonize.py in.grib2 --float -q -f "geoJSON"  out.json layer fieldname
```

This works fine but it is merging polygons of the same value. How do I stop it from doing this?

I see a "connectedness" parameter in the gdal documentation, but I am not positive this is what I need. Just in case, I tried it anyway like so (set to zero) :

gdal_polygonize.py -0 in.grib2 --float -q -f "geoJSON"  out.json layer fieldname

However, this gives me a usage warning. I cannot put "-0" anywhere in the command without a usage warning, or any other number for that matter. Am I on the right track or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't stop gdal_polygonize from connecting polygons. Connected pixels with the same value will always be output as a single polygon, not individual polygons.

From the [documentation](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_polygonize.html#description) (emphasis mine):

> This utility creates vector polygons for **all connected regions of pixels in the raster sharing a common pixel value**.

You can't even modify the python code as the C++ algorithm ([`GDALPolygonize()`](https://gdal.org/api/gdal_alg.html#_CPPv414GDALPolygonize15GDALRasterBandH15GDALRasterBandH9OGRLayerHiPPc16GDALProgressFuncPv)) it is based on is what is connecting the pixels.

An alternative using QGIS is to use the [Vector Creation -> Raster Pixels to Polygons](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html?highlight=centroid#raster-pixels-to-polygons) processing tool which will not join connected pixels.

[image]

Note: make sure you don't use the [GDAL -> Raster Conversion -> Polygonize (raster to vector)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterconversion.html#polygonize-raster-to-vector) processing tool in QGIS , it uses `gdal_polygonize` behind the scenes.